# Handsontable change a column source

Tags: handsontable

Is it possible to change the source in a Handsontable instance when inside an event?

Below is my code:

```
var container2 = $('#example2');

var hot2 = new Handsontable(container2, {
    data: {},
    minRows: 5,
    colHeaders: ['Car', 'Year', 'Car Color'],
    columns: [
        {
            type: 'autocomplete',
            source: ['BMW', 'Chrysler', 'Nissan', 'Suzuki', 'Toyota', 'Volvo'],
            strict: true,
            allowInvalid: false
        }, ,
        {},
        {
            type: 'autocomplete',
            source: ['yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue', 'gray', 'black', 'white', 'purple', 'lime', 'olive', 'cyan'],
            strict: true,
            allowInvalid: false
        }]
});

Handsontable.hooks.add('afterChange', afterChangedCallback, hot2);

function afterChangedCallback(p) {
    console.log(p);
    if (p[0][1] == 0) {
        alert('This means the first column has changed, I now want to update the colors here');
    }
}
```

When a user selects a different car brand, I only want to populate the dropdown of "Car Color" with certain colors. Thus, not all car brands has the same colors.

**EDIT**

I updated the callback function to this based on the accepted answer:

```
function afterChanged(p) {
    console.log(p);
    if (p[0][1] == 0) {
        hot2.updateSettings({
            cells: function (row, col, prop) {
                if (row == p[0][0] && col == 2) {
                    var cellProperties = {};

                    cellProperties.source = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];

                    return cellProperties;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, you can use the `updateSettings` method to change the source of an entire column or particular cell. You probably want per-cell so I would do:

```
hot.updateSettings({
    cells: newCellDefinitionFunction()
})
```

Of course this new definition is up to you to figure out. It could just be returning the same `cellProperties` each time but check on some global array for what sources to use for which cells.